# FF8 Phoenix Pinion

Tags: final-fantasy-8

I'm confused about Phoenix being summoned by the "Phoenix Pinon". According to [finalfantasy.wikia.com:](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Phoenix_Pinion)

> Summons Phoenix if used in battle, fully reviving all KO'ed allies and dealing Fire damage to all opponents. Once Phoenix has been summoned once, it has a random chance to appear to save the player from a Game Over. The more in the player's inventory, the greater the chance of Phoenix appearing.

Does that mean Phoenix will only appear in the battle the pinon was used? Or is there a chance it will appear in any battle thereafter (similar to Odin) without having to use another pinon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When used in battle, it summons Pheonix and revives all downed party to ~12% of their maximum HP. Afterwards in subsequent battles, it can randomly appear (similar to how Odin and Gilgamesh appear randomly at the beginning of a battle) when your party gets KOed in subsequent battles at a fixed rate (about 1/4th of the time).

In FFVIII, it makes no difference how many you have in your inventory, it's at a fixed rate. Only in FFIX, does having more pinions affect the auto-summon rate (*X*/254, where *X* <= 99).